# polynomial approximation for $\frac{1}{1-x}$

Tags: real-analysis, approximation-theory

Prove that for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$ there exists a polynomial $P$ such that $\deg P=n$ and 
$$
\sup_{x\in\left[0,\frac{1}{2}\right]}\left| P(x)-\frac{1}{1-x}\right|\ <\ \frac{4}{(\sqrt{2}+1)^{2n+2}}
$$

---

I tried with the incomplete $\frac{1}{1-x}$, i.e. $1+x+\dots+x^n$, but it doesn't work for $x=\frac{1}{2}$ and close values.

Comment: HIint (I haven't tried). Consider the Taylor series about $x=1/4$.

Comment: correct me if I'm wrong:
the $k$-th derivative of $\frac{1}{1-x}$ seems to be $\frac{k!}{1-x)^{k+1}}$, so for such $P$ we would have $LHS=\frac{4}{3}\sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{3^k}=\frac{2}{3}\frac{1}{3^n}$ what is bigger then needed

Comment: Tight bounds for absolute errors of polynomial approximations usually lead to answers involving Tchebyschev polynomials.